# browser crashes after a few pagination applied in pageable collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, pagination, backbone-paginator

I am working with backbone pageable collection which extends backbone collection.

I have a `paginator` which can move our pages in the came from pageable collection.

I am working upon server side mode of backbone pageable collection.

The problem is when i paginate 5-6 times from the `paginator`. Chrome crashes as it increases the memory for storing current collection. And perhaps it is not destroying the previously stored collection.

I am doing the following to solve the problem :

```
this.collection.getPage(pageNo).success(function(result) {
              this.collection.remove();
            });
```

I was expecting this.collection.remove() to clear the memory used. But it actually doesn't. But the above does not solve the problem.

Has anybody find this problem earlier?
How did you solved the problem?

Comment: I am guessing you refresh view based on the add event, and adding multiple items will call it multiple times, causing Chrome to halt. Can you show your view rendering code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard without seeing your paginator's code.
Anyway, first of all calling `this.collection.remove()` does nothing without passing as argument a model or an array of model (see the [official documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-remove)).

So I suggest you to do this instead (assuming that result contain a valid array of models)

```
this.collection.getPage(pageNo).success(function(result) {
    this.collection.reset(result);
});
```

Calling reset will replace the collection's models with new ones. Again, to find out more, read the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset)!

Comment: Without seeing all the code involved it's just a guessing game. Try to log your collection before and after calling reset to check if your collection contain the correct models. It that's the case the problem lies elsewhere.